# heapusage is not displaying function names for the program under analysis

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I'm trying to use [heapusage](https://github.com/d99kris/heapusage) to find memory leaks in the version of mencoder I'm using (as it happens 1.3.0, the most recent release).

mencoder was built locally, and was configured with '--enable-debug'.

The heapusage output looks like this:

```
==29017== 4096 bytes in 1 block(s) are lost, originally allocated at:
==29017==    at 0xb7fcd1c2: realloc + 72
==29017==    at 0x00269f75:
==29017==    at 0x00267e4d:
==29017==    at 0x002680d0:
==29017==    at 0x002716ae:
==29017==    at 0x00271bd4:
==29017==    at 0x0029af09:
==29017==    at 0x00262f64:
==29017==    at 0xb79dad36: __libc_start_main + 230
==29017==    at 0x00260655:
```

The names I've got here are all from the C library, and I'd very much like to get names for all those addresses.

Things I've attempted: 
`addr2line -f -e mencoder 0x00269f75` - This tells me that the call is from a part of the code that clearly is NOT involved (that address is in rtsp network code, and I'm reading from a USB video camera).

Disabled ASLR - which shouldn't (and didn't) produce any behavioral change on this level, but makes it much simpler to compare runs.

If someone could school me on how to get actual information out of this tool, I'd be appreciative.

(NOTE: I have also tried valgrind on this code, but it just barfs when run.)

Comment: valgrind barfs!  what does that mean?  What parameters/options did you pass to valgrind?   There are several areas within the standard C libraries that 'seem' to result in memory leaks. They don't actually have memory leaks and (at least with valgrind) library functions can be ignored via the appropriate parameter/option

Comment: On the valgrind front, it craps out with 'Illegal instruction' - basically valgrind can't figure out the code it's trying to instrument. Given that mencoder is doing a lot of things in custom written ASM for speed reasons, this is not totally unreasonable. I have reported the bug to the valgrind bugtracker, but since it's on 32 bit, it's unlikely to get any traction. I get the same problem if I build everything for 64 bit on a 64 bit OS (just a different set of opcodes that cause the illegal instruction). I haven't had a chance to put that bug report in, however.

Comment: it should be mentioned that the C libraries are 'stripped' so have no line number, symbol table, etc info available.

Comment: what is `mencoder`  The referenced link is to `heapusage`, not `mencoder`

Comment: the `addr2line` utility can also be run with the input from stdin.  Suggest running *heapusage executableName | awk (to extract just the addresses) | addr2line -e executableName*  And remember that 'executableName' must be compiled/linked with the `-g` or `-ggdb` or `-ggdb3` option so that symbol names, line numbers, function names are available within the executable file

Comment: one more thing,  When compiling/linking your program, DO NOT apply any optimization as that tends to modify a lot of the executable code

Comment: -g was turned on, and I have now tried without -O in CFLAGS, and it still doesn't give me anything useful. I'm going to put some trace statements into mencoder to try to learn the actual addresses of some things and see if I can work out what's going on from there.

Comment: mencoder is a program for video encoding, which is probably one of the WORST things you'd want to run a tool like this against, as it has a lot of hand-coded ASM for speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I spent a day digging through the options that get set for mencoder and finally found the last thing that was getting in the way.

To configure mencoder so that HeapUsage can correctly output the locations where things leak from, I had to do the following:

```
./configure --disable-gnutls --enable-debug --disable-relocatable
```

Then hand-modify the output config.mak as follows:

```
Remove -O options from CFLAGS & HOSTCFLAGS
Remove -Wl,--version-script,binary.ver from EXTRALIBS
```

It took me a while and several rounds of minimizing changes to figure out that it was the linker option that was ultimately causing the problems. NOW I can get on with the fixing memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

using the command:

```
heapusage --help
```

causes all the user info for usage of this utility to be listed on stdout.

There is no feature to tell it to ignore the standard C libraries. So it will output a lot of incorrect claims to memory leaks.

The `-n` option can be used to tell it to not perform symbol lookup.

My suspicion is your local version has been modified from the original to not ever perform symbol lookup.

Suggest you download your own copy of the heapusage source from gethub.
compile/link/install it, all on your own computer

here is the results of a run using a small local file that calls `calloc()` and `free()`

Note: the `apple apple grape` are the outputs from the specific program and can be ignored.

```
./heapusage -n ~/Documents/forum/untitled1
apple
apple
grape
==17050== Heapusage - https://github.com/d99kris/heapusage
==17050== 
==17050== HEAP SUMMARY:
==17050==     in use at exit: 1024 bytes in 1 blocks
==17050==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 1056 bytes allocated
==17050== 
==17050== 1024 bytes in 1 block(s) are lost, originally allocated at:
==17050==    at 0x00007f815961609d
==17050==    at 0x00007f815929a1d5
==17050==    at 0x00007f81592a8594
==17050==    at 0x00007f81592a78f8
==17050==    at 0x00007f81592a628d
==17050==    at 0x00007f815929c738
==17050==    at 0x0000000000400b0d
==17050==    at 0x00007f815924d830
==17050==    at 0x0000000000400849
==17050== 
==17050== LEAK SUMMARY:
==17050==    definitely lost: 1024 bytes in 1 blocks
==17050==
```

and here is the results of the same run, on the same file, without the `-n` option

```
 ./heapusage ~/Documents/forum/untitled1
apple
apple
grape
==16969== Heapusage - https://github.com/d99kris/heapusage
==16969== 
==16969== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16969==     in use at exit: 1024 bytes in 1 blocks
==16969==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 1056 bytes allocated
==16969== 
==16969== 1024 bytes in 1 block(s) are lost, originally allocated at:
==16969==    at 0x00007f2877e2e09d: malloc + 49
==16969==    at 0x00007f2877ab21d5: _IO_file_doallocate + 85
==16969==    at 0x00007f2877ac0594: _IO_doallocbuf + 52
==16969==    at 0x00007f2877abf8f8: _IO_file_overflow + 456
==16969==    at 0x00007f2877abe28d: _IO_file_xsputn + 173
==16969==    at 0x00007f2877ab4738: _IO_puts + 168
==16969==    at 0x0000000000400b0d: 
==16969==    at 0x00007f2877a65830: __libc_start_main + 240
==16969==    at 0x0000000000400849: 
==16969== 
==16969== LEAK SUMMARY:
==16969==    definitely lost: 1024 bytes in 1 blocks
==16969==
```

Comment: If you'll notice, in my snippet, you can see lookups have happened for symbols in the standard library, just not for anything in the program under debug, so it's not that it's not doing symbol lookup at all, it's that it for some reason can't lookup these symbols peroperly. And I built heapusage myself from source, so I know there's nothing too weird in there.

Comment: Any ideas on how to manually map from the heapusage output back to my program's symbols would be appreciated - I've tried looking at the map files and using addr2line, both of which produce the same nonsensical results (functions are identified that don't call the routines in question).